# Output of Erlang bit packing

Tags: erlang

I am not able to understand bit packing in erlang.

Suppose:

`R=4`, `G=6` and `B=8`

then why is the output like this:

`<< R:5,G:5,B:6 >>`

output: `<<33,136>>`.

I don't get it. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<< R:5,G:5,B:6 >>
```

This record we allocate 5,5 and 6 bits, and the result is a 2-byte binary sequence. To better understand why this happens, start the reverse conversion. Transform numbers 33 and 136 in binary form:

```
integer_to_list(33,2).
integer_to_list(136,2).
```

"100001"
"10001000"

We get the following lines. Since each segment of the binary sequence is a multiple of 8, supplement the presentation of 33 zeros to the left.

```
L2=lists:append("00",lists:append(integer_to_list(33,2),integer_to_list(136,2))).
```

"0010000110001000"

Proceed to the decoding of. The third argument indicates the number of bits

```
V1 = list_to_integer(lists:sublist(L2,5),2).
V2 = list_to_integer(lists:sublist(L2,6,5),2).
V3 = list_to_integer(lists:sublist(L2,11,6),2).
```

4
6
8

Sorry for my English,hope I explained clearly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, it made it clear and answered the question.